# How to establish websocket connection from angular-socketio to flask-socketio

Tags: angular, flask, flask-socketio, angular-socket-io

I am new to web socket, i'm implementing web socket server using flask-socketio, and angular-socketio as client,

i use this code in flask

> application.py

```
@socketio.on('connect', namespace='/test')
def test_connect():    
    print('Client connected')
```

and i use this code in angular service to connect to flask server

> socket.service.ts

```
    import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
    import * as io from "socket.io-client";
    import { Observable } from "rxjs";

    @Injectable({
      providedIn: "root"
    })
    export class SocketService {      
      private socket;

      constructor() {        
        this.socket = io("/test"); // i get example by connect using flask namespace
this.socket = io("localhost:5000"); // i tried this
this.socket = io(`/api`); // i also tried this

      }

      public sendMessage(message) {
        this.socket.emit("new-message", message);
      }

      public getMessages = () => {
        return Observable.create(observer => {
          this.socket.on("new-message", message => {
            observer.next(message);
          });
        });
      };
    }
```

i also try to connect to flask server using localhost:5000 as the URL, but it leads CORS problem, and after facing that issue i also try to connect using '/api' from proxy.config.json below as the url

```
{
  "/api": {
  "target": "http://127.0.0.1:5000",
  "secure": false,
  "pathRewrite": {
      "^/api": ""
  }
  }
}
```

this is my app.component

> app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { SocketService } from "./socket.service";

@Component({
  selector: "app-root",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = "angularsocketio";

  constructor(private socketService: SocketService) {}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Socket.IO server needs to be configured appropriately if you need to access it from across domains. See the `cors_allowed_origins` option in the [documentation](https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#cross-origin-controls).

The default URL for a Socket.IO service is `/socket.io`. Both the client and the server need to be told if you want to use a different URL. For the server, this is the `path` option, also [documented](https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#flask_socketio.SocketIO).

Comment: you mean that flask socket connection is not on localhost:5000? What about on the client side? how to connect to flask socketio?

Comment: thank you so much, i solve it by using cors_allowed_origins='*' in SocketIO arguments

Comment: anyway, it is safe for production to allow all cors? how to configure it jut for my angular client?

Comment: It is not safe to allow all origins in production. You should set `cors_allowed_origins` to the origin(s) used by your application. For example, if you host your angular app at https://example.com, then pass `cors_allowed_origins='https://example.com'`.

Comment: thank you so much, now i am having this situation, my angular is currently local, in localhost:4200, when i set cors_allowed_origins='http://localhost:4200' nothing wrong and everything work as expected, but when i set cors_allowed_origins='http://127.0.0.1:4200' or cors_allowed_origins='http://0.0.0.0:4200' or even cors_allowed_origins='{myIP}:4200' it doesn't work, do you have any clue?

Comment: Look at the error in the browser's console. It will tell you exactly what the origin is. You should use exactly what the browser indicates. For example, you are missing the http:// or https:// in your examples.

Comment: Do you mind sharing a snippet of the code on the server side, where do I put the cors_allowed_origins option?

Comment: @LibbyLebyane this option is an argument to the `SocketIO` object.

Comment: @Miguel Thank you for your response. I finally got it to work, when I had set, it was showing me a different error on the server side, which said Unknown Protocol for Socket.IO or Engine.IO used, so I switched from the `NPM Socket.IO-Client` package to a Cloud Flare hosted script which did the trick for me.